# Replacing a subquery

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to get the total earnings of a painter to be displayed after a gallery's commission has been deducted, according to the painter's ID number. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT painter.ptr_num, painter.ptr_firstname, (SUM() - 
(gallery.gal_rate*painting.ptng_price)) AS Earnings
FROM painting,painter,gallery
GROUP BY painter.ptr_num
```

As you may have noticed, the sum is empty and that's because the only way I can think of to achieve the above is to have a subquery.

Here is the Painting table that must be included in the sum:

**Painting**

> **Ptng_Price**     **Ptr_Num**
>        24                  100
>        85                  101
>        34                  102
>        17                  103

Any additional information will be available upon request. Thanks in advance for any help!

ERD...
[image]

Comment: Are the painters paid on just their paintings, or on the total of `painting.ptng_price` for all painters?

Comment: how do painting, painter, and gallery relate?  You seem to be missing some relationships; which otherwise result in a cartesean product and likely improper results.  There's a few other problems here as well.. How do we know when a sale has occurred?  Do galleries make commission on unsold paintings?

Comment: @Michael Painters are paid only for their own paintings.

Comment: @xQbert I can post the ER diagram if that would help.

Comment: Er diagram or DDL (structure) for tables

Comment: @xQbert Here you go.

http://imgur.com/swyOBzI

Couldn't upload due to reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all records in table Painting are "Sold" paintings and thus should be aggregated (Summed) into the Earnings.

What this does calculate the Earnings on a per painting basis then sum them up grouping by number and first name

```
SELECT P.ptr_num, 
       P.ptr_firstname, 
       sum(obj.ptng_price - (G.gal_rate*obj.ptng_price)) AS Earnings
FROM painting obj
INNER JOIN painter P
 on obj.Ptr_num = P.Ptr_num
INNER JOIN gallery G
 on obj.Gal_num = G.Gal_Num
GROUP BY P.ptr_num, 
       P.ptr_firstname,
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.Thank you very very much! I feel a little stupid not realizing the mistake now.

Comment: we all go there.  Sometimes a fresh pair of eyes is needed.  That's what makes this site so amazing.  Quick help and more than one set of eyes.